# SQL Server Security Option w/ Intermediate Check Option? What does that mean?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

This afternoon I was reviewing the security for a user in my SQL Server, in SQL Server Management Studio.  I opened the Database User's Properties dialog, and went to the Securables section.

As I was cycling through the tables and stored procedures that this particular user had access to, I noticed that one of the data tables had the the Update option checked in an intermediate state.  What does that mean?  You can either update a row, or you can't.  There is no in-between.  I've included an image for reference.  I would just fully check this option and save it but I'd rather not screw with the DB if this serves a worthwhile purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that means that that permission has been inherited and wasn't explicitly set for that user.

> The GRANT statement can assign
>   permissions to a group or role that
>   can be inherited by database users.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669084.aspx

I'm trying to find something that specifically spells out that's what the checkbox looks like in the above situation.

Comment: That's probably the case.  My SQL User Accounts are derived from Active Directory groups.  The AD Group associated with this account is also a member of another, similar AD group. The parent is a "Read" group, and the child (the one in the picture above) is suppose to be the update group.  Interesting, though, of the many tables associated with this group, this is the only one that has a permission option in an intermediate state!?

Comment: Abe,  I'm going to mark this as the answer because I suspect that's the case.  I am interested, however, in if you can fine definitive documentation confirming your assumption.  To be sure, yes, looked too and couldn't find it.